# Gmail was accessed by IMAP from a different state, security measures to employ?

Tags: gmail, passwords, gmail-imap

My Gmail account appears to have been accessed by IMAP from California. I am in Illinois.

```
IMAP     United States (CA) (208.87.200.182)    11:20 pm (38 minutes ago)
Browser  United States (IL) (98.253.XX.XX)      11:19 pm (39 minutes ago)
IMAP     United States (CA) (208.87.200.183)    11:00 pm (58 minutes ago)
IMAP     United States (CA) (208.87.200.182)    8:54 pm  (3 hours ago)
```

I have now disabled IMAP and POP3 for my mail and added additional secondary security to my mail that sends an SMS to my phone.

What more can I to protect my account? Did I forget anything? I am really freaked out here. I change my password frequently. How can someone else get access to my email?

Comment: Happened to me too.

Answer (score 6):

I'd change your password.

It looks like those IPs that accessed your email were from this company:

http://www.seven.com

I'm not familiar with their software, but it looks like they offer some mobile apps that could have accessed your email.

I don't think anything malicious is going on.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a cell phone or mobile device that configured to receive your gmail or use the google calendar or  any of google services? I am  pretty sure that your cellphone or mobile device is accessing to your google account services as skrewler said it is an IO address from seven.com and seems like seven.com makes lost of mobile applications.